# MongoDB find Query comparision with CurrentDate

Tags: mongodb

I want to fetch current day documents from a MongoDB collection. My documents look like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("55743941789a9abe7f4af3fd"), 
    "msisdn" : "9xxxxxxxxxx", 
    "act_date" : ISODate("2014-11-24T00:00:00Z"), 
    "date" : ISODate("2015-06-07T00:00:00Z"), 
    "recharge" : { "recharge_amt" : 0, "rechargetype" : "WEB" },
    "voice" : { "local_og_mou" : 20, "local_other_mobile_og_mou" : 0, "nld_og_mou" : 0, "nld_other_mobile_og_mou" : 10 }, 
    "gprs" : { "total_access_count" : 1, "total_datavolume_mb" : 42 }, 
    "sms" : { "freesms" : 3, "local_sms_count" : 0, "nat_sms_count" : 0, "inter_sms_count" : 0 } 
}
```

Comment: Be more clear with your edit....

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/

Comment: add your document structure for more clarification.

Comment: Hi Dev,Below is the data structure...

Comment: { "_id" : ObjectId("55743941789a9abe7f4af3fd"), "msisdn" : "9xxxxxxxxxx", "act_date" : ISODate("2014-11-24T00:00:00Z"), "date" : ISODate("2015-06-07T00:00:00Z"), "recharge" : { "recharge_amt" : 0, "rechargetype" : "WEB" }, "voice" : { "local_og_mou" : 20, "local_other_mobile_og_mou" : 0, "nld_og_mou" : 0, "nld_other_mobile_og_mou" : 10 }, "gprs" : { "total_access_count" : 1, "total_datavolume_mb" : 42 }, "sms" : { "freesms" : 3, "local_sms_count" : 0, "nat_sms_count" : 0, "inter_sms_count" : 0 } }

Comment: We have 30 days data like this.How  to fetch current day data. here condition field is "date"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As per your question ***you want to fetch current day documents from a mongodb collection***. In mongoDB shell when you type `new Date()` it gives you current date with time and this value always vary when you run same `new Date()` so probably your query like this :

```
db.collectionName.find({"start_date":new Date()}).pretty()
```

But, I think this query return the those documents which will presents in your collection but same current `Date` value may be not presents in your documents SO this case you should use following

```
db.collectionName.find({"start_date":{"$lte":new Date()}}).pretty()
```

Or

```
db.collectionName.find({"start_date":{"$gte":new Date()}}).pretty()
```

In some case If you want to find exact match with `year,month,day` then you should use [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) with [$year,$month,$dayOfMonth in $project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/) like this :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$project": {
    "year": {
      "$year": "$date"
    },
    "month": {
      "$month": "$date"
    },
    "day": {
      "$dayOfMonth": "$date"
    }
  }
}, {
  "$match": {
    "year": new Date().getFullYear(),
    "month": new Date().getMonth() + 1, //because January starts with 0
    "day": new Date().getDate()
  }
})
```

In above aggregation query will return those documents which match current date like `year,month,day` of current date. Also you replace `$match` as

```
var currentDate = new Date()

 {
  "$match": {
    "year": currentDate.getFullYear(),
    "month": currentDate.getMonth() + 1, //because January starts with 0
    "day": currentDate.getDate()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) you can include `timeStamp: true` after your schema definition to get autogenerated createdAt and updatedAt fields, Mongoose will take care of it.

```
const itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    // Your Schema definition here
}, {
  timestamps: true
})
```

In your case, you need to compare your TimeStamp key with the start of today which is **12 AM** with ISO string as `2019-11-08T00:00:00.000Z` and end of the day which is **11:59 PM** with ISO string as `2019-11-08T23:59:59.999Z`.
The below code will do it for you.

```
let queryObj = {}
const startOfDay = new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).toISOString()
const endOfDay = new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(23, 59, 59, 999)).toISOString()
    
queryObj.createdAt = {
  $gte: startOfDay, // 2019-11-08T00:00:00.000Z
  $lt: endOfDay // 2019-11-08T23:59:59.999Z
}

let items = item.find(obj)
// new Date().setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0) Generates this weird string '1573171200000' which is not a human readable format of TimeStamp
// To convert it into ISO String we have .toISOString() method
```

Comment: This uses mongoose. The OP said nothing about using mongoose. MongoDB will *not* "take care of it".

Comment: My bad @DanDascalescu , updated the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using below query.

```
db.collection.find({"start_date" : { $gte : new ISODate("2015-05-27T00:00:00Z") }});
```

Note : above query will return documents which are greather than specified date.

**To find a date that equals another date**

```
db.collection.find({"start_date" : new ISODate("2015-05-27T00:00:00Z") });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simpler expression match as below:

```
$match: {
  $expr: {$eq: [{$year: '$start_date'}, {$year: new Date()}]},
  $expr: {$eq: [{$month: '$start_date'}, {$month: new Date()}]},
  $expr: {$eq: [{$day: '$start_date'}, {$day: new Date()}]},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB v5.0+, you can perform date-only comparison(without time) by using `$dateTrunc`. Compare with `$$NOW` to get documents in the current date.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $dateTrunc: {
              date: "$startDate",
              unit: "day"
            }
          },
          {
            $dateTrunc: {
              date: "$$NOW",
              unit: "day"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/26ZiJqCeWP1)