# MongoError: can’t convert from BSON type string to Date in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In Meteor JS I want to find users whose birthday is today.I have this piece of code that runs fine on my computer (locally) but it fails in production :

```
let today = new Date()
let users = Meteor.users.find({
    "status.lastLogin": { $not: { $eq: null } },
    $expr: {
        $and: [
            {
                $eq: [
                    {
                        $dayOfMonth: {
                            date: "$profile.birthdate",
                            timezone: "Europe/Paris",
                        },
                    },
                    today.getDate(),
                ],
            },
            {
                $eq: [
                    {
                        $month: {
                            date: "$profile.birthdate",
                            timezone: "Europe/Paris",
                        },
                    },
                    today.getMonth() + 1,
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
})
```

My server is hosted on Galaxy and the DB on mongodb.com
[I checked the profile.birthdate type and it is Date on mongodb.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYbrA.png)
The error is :

> MongoError: can’t convert from BSON type string to Date\n at
> Connection.
> (/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:450:61)\n
> at Connection.emit (events.js:311:20)\n at
> Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)\n at processMessage
> (/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:384:10)\n
> at TLSSocket.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how can I fix it?

**Edit**: By following @Jankapunkt advice to use aggregate and by reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772285/mongodb-find-query-comparision-with-currentdate), I was able to write a better (I think...) query and now it is working.
This is the new code:

```
const today = new Date()
let users = Meteor.users.aggregate(
    {
        $project: {
            status: "$status",
            roles: "$roles",
            month: {
                $month: {
                    date: "$profile.birthdate",
                    timezone: "Europe/Paris",
                },
            },
            day: {
                $dayOfMonth: {
                    date: "$profile.birthdate",
                    timezone: "Europe/Paris",
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "status.lastLogin": { $ne: null },
            roles: "candidate",
            month: today.getMonth() + 1,
            day: today.getDate(),
        },
    }
)
```

Comment: Why don't you just check the fields against the date object? Meteor's ejson makes many of the Date conversion obsolete. Second, $dayOfMonth is an aggregate function and you need an extra package for aggregates. Edit: You may ask in the forums and refer to this post, since this can easily expand to a larger discussion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jankapunkt but I still don't know what to do. Could you elaborate on "Why don't you just check the fields against the date object?" and reading EJSON doc didn't help me either.

Comment: I already posted this question on Meteor forums six days ago and there are no answers : https://forums.meteor.com/t/mongoerror-cant-convert-from-bson-type-string-to-date/52942

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here, I'd like to address:

- `$expr` is usually only required in rare cases or when matching against a regular expression.
- `$dayOfMonth` is an aggregate operator and not available in basic queries, but there are [packages available](https://github.com/sakulstra/meteor-aggregate)
- Meteor has builtin Date support through EJSON, which extends BSON by custom types (it abstracts the type conversion away for you):

```js
Meteor.publish('allbirthdays', function () {
  const today = new Date()
  // correct timezone here
  return Meteor.users.find({ '$profile.birthdate': today })
}
```

No need to convert Date to some mongo operators etc.

- `$and` is a contradiction if differnt values are both required for the same field (`birthdate` can never be today and today in a month), did you intend to use `$or`?
- `{ $not: { $eq: null } }` can be written as `{ $ne: null }`
- Always disable the `services` field if you publish users! Services contains the (hashed) password and other oauth providers, including resume token, which could lead to serious security issues:

### Saving / querying Dates without aggregate

The above methods allow only an exact Date matches, because MongoDB provides Date-specific query only through `aggregate`.

Therefore, your options are:

- A) Use the aggregate package to build `$expr` for `$month` and `$dayOfMonth` as in your example code
- B) Create the birthday only as locale field (which makes it a `String` type):

```js
export const getDate = () => {
  // todo apply locale, timezone etc.
  return new Date().toLocaleString(undefined, {
    day: 'numeric', month: 'long' 
  })
}
```

and save it in the user's collection as a separate field (e.g. `birthDay`):

```js
Meteor.users.update(userId, {
  $set: {
    '$profile.birthDay': getDate() // "June 3"
  }
})
```

ans query only for this day:

```js
Meteor.publish('allbirthdays', function () {
  const today = getDate()
  return Meteor.users.find({ '$profile.birthDay': today })
}
```

- C) Save the month and day as `Number` types in separate fields:

```js
const today = new Date()
Meteor.users.update(userId, {
  $set: {
    '$profile.birthDay': today.getDate()  // 3
    '$profile.birthMon': today.getMonth() // 6
  }
})
```

ans query only for this day:

```js
Meteor.publish('allbirthdays', function () {
  const today = new Date()
  return Meteor.users.find({
    '$profile.birthDay': today.getDate()
    '$profile.birthMon': today.getMonth()
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks again for your comment @Jankapunkt. Everything makes sense except for your example with the query. Your query will find users who are born today, not users whose birthday is today. How do you compare only the date and month, and not the year?

Comment: I followed your advice to use aggregate and I made a new query that you can see in my edited post. Unfortunately I get the exact same error as before. So the problem must lies somewhere else.

Comment: After testing again, I can see that it is working so I will mark this answer as correct.