# mongodb comparing date entry with current date

Tags: mongodb, timestamp

I want to aggregate entries whose date is *less than* 1 week old from *today*.

```
{
    "collection": "my-lovely-collection",
    "aggregate": [
        {"$match": {"some_field": { "$regex": "awesome*"}}},
        {"$match": {"created": {"$lt":
            {"$dateToString":
                {"date":
                    {"$dateSubtract":
                        {"startDate": {"$currentDate": {"$type": "date"}},
                        "unit": "day",
                        "amount": 7
                    }}}}}}},
        {"$group": {"_id": "$some_field", "count": {"$sum": 1 }}},
        {"$sort":  [{"name": "count", "direction": 1}]}
    ]
}
```

When I use a hard-coded date for today everything works fine (but that's not what I want)

```
{"$match": {"created": {"$lt": "2022-08-29"}}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB find Query comparision with CurrentDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772285/mongodb-find-query-comparision-with-currentdate)

Comment: @DimiVi I can't seem to subtract 7 days from today and compare to that - even after using `new Date()` - any ideas? thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$dateSubtract`:

```js
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $lt: [
          "$created",
          {
            $dateToString: {
              format: "%Y-%m-%d",
              date: {
                $dateSubtract: {
                  startDate: "$$NOW",
                  unit: "week",
                  amount: 1
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Mongo Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/QWT4ar4gbt0

Documentation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateSubtract/

Comment: I can't seem to subtract 7 days from today and compare to that

Comment: Gotcha. Updated my answer

Comment: Arrrggghh ... still not working - You don't use the `"$dateToString"` - is it not needed? (you also have a typo with an extra `$` in `"$created"`

Comment: @OrenIshShalom so I assume your `created` field is a `string`. If yes so I updated my answer in accordance, please take a peek. If no, please provide your collection schema for better visibility :)

Comment: thanks for the mongo playground link !